# Why did the governments of the distant past last longer than those of the present/recent past?

Tags: ancient-rome, ancient-egypt, government, timeline

For example, Rome and Egypt existed for massive amounts of time that pretty much any modern nation could not. Is this a selection bias on my end (comparing the most successful empires of the past to all modern empires, where I should rather pick something like the ottomans which existed for ~521 years) or is there a legitimate reason why this seems to be the case?

(Apologies for bad tagging, I couldn't find any good ones. Mods, please edit the tags if there are ones that fit better)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130811/discussion-on-question-by-tuatarian-why-did-the-governments-of-the-distant-past).

Answer (score 5):

In general, they didn't.

First off, some terms. Technically a [nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nation) is a coherent culture of people, so polyglot *empires* like Rome's or the Ottoman's don't qualify. It would probably be better to talk about Governments, or [Sovereign States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovereign_state).

Let's look at Rome. It was around from 509BC to 1453AD by some accounts.

However, it wasn't at all the same government that whole period. In fact, its timeline of governments up until the fall of the western Roman Empire looks more like this:

- Prior to 509BC : Kingdom
- 509BC-387BC(122 years) : Oligarchic City-State Republic
- 387BC-90BC(297 years) : City-State Republic
- 90BC-25BC(65 years) : Republic
- 25BC-293AD (318 years) : Empire
- 293AD-476AD (183 years) : Dual Empire

Likewise, for the Ottomans:

- 1299AD-1603 (304 years) : [Blood Tanistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanistry#Blood_tanistry) [Absolute Monarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_monarchy)
- 1603-1839 (236 years) : Inherited Empire
- 1839-1922 (83 years) : Constitutional Monarchy

Note that some of the dates here are debatable, but the point isn't the exact dates, but rather that in no case did the state actually exist for longer than a bit over 300 years without having a major change in how its government functioned and how its leaders were selected.

If you look at the [list of Egyptian Dynasties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynasties_of_ancient_Egypt), you see the same story: the longest-lasting one was about 275 years, and very few broke the 200 year mark.

Comment: As an aside, I've seen people count the USA as the longest-running government under this kind of definition. However, many historians consider the US Civil war, and the reconstruction amendments that followed it, as sort of a second founding. Before then it operated more as a tight Confederation, none of the Bill of Rights applied to the sub-states, and the original system restricted voting to white male property owners in most places. So you could argue a split in the US to two systems of roughly 100 and 150 years (and a third to include the Articles of Confederation).

Comment: Regarding your comment "many historians..." Two points: (1) Don't forget that all academics are under continuous pressure to publish something novel as long as it can be colored plausible and (2) That sounds like just one more battle in the eternal war between the lumpers and the splitters. (Which, when you get down to it, is the essence of *any* answer to this question.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124978/discussion-between-t-e-d-and-mark-olson).

Comment: You make some good points here. The history of many countries that are sometimes considered "continuous" have in fact been ruled by various dynasties that rose to overthrow the previous. Consider France - is the Ancien Régime the same state as modern-day Republican France? China is also a good example, and one can make an argument that Imperial Russia, the USSR, and modern-day Russia are in fact the same state with three ruling dynasties.

Answer (score -2):

As [pointed out by Karl Marx](https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1848/communist-manifesto/ch01.htm#007), technological and scientific progress will lead to economic and social changes, and economic and social changes will lead to political changes.

Technological and scientific progress, and accompanying changes in production and labour relations, have been much faster in the last few hundred years than in antiquity.